# regex help. modify regex to exclude content within curly braces

Tags: regex, regex-negation

In javascript, my regex is:

```
let regEx = new RegExp("([A-Za-z])(?!([^<]+)?>)", "gi");
```

My string is:

```
<span class="customer-key">{aaa}</span>bbb {ccc}
```

In the above example, the regex matches `"aaa"`, `"bbb"` and `"ccc"`.

I would like to update my regex to EXCLUDE anything WITHIN curly braces, so that it ONLY matches `"bbb"`.

How can I update the regex to do so? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try (your regexp separate letters so my too)

```js
let regEx = new RegExp("([A-Za-z])(?!([^<]+)?>)(?!([^{]+)?})", "gi");
let str= '<span class="customer-key">{aaa}</span>bbb {ccc}'

let s =str.match(regEx);

console.log(s)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get bbb , one option could be to use the dom, find the textnode(s) and remove the content between curly braces:

```js
const htmlString = `<span class="customer-key">{aaa}</span>bbb {ccc}`;
let div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlString;
div.childNodes.forEach(x => {
  if (x.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
    console.log(x.textContent.replace(/{[^}]+}/g, ''));
  }
});
```

Note that parsing [html with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) is not advisable.

If you want to get `bbb` from your example string, another option could be to match what you don't want to keep and to replace that with an empty string.

```js
const regex = /\s*<[^>]+>\s*|\s*{[^}]+}\s*/gm;
const str = `<span class="customer-key">{aaa}</span>bbb {ccc}`;
const result = str.replace(regex, '');
console.log(result);
```